# Send email after every interval of time in php without using ajax

Tags: php

I am making web application in **PHP**. I need to send mail to my users after **every interval of time** (say after every two days). How can i keep track of time intervals in php (assume i know the **start time**).

Comment: Create a cron job.

Comment: That is exactly what crons are for.  [Here is a reference](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a cron job that runs one of your php scripts locally, and have that script check against a database to see whether or not the time is appropriate to send the email. For example,

In your crontab:

```
0 0 */2 * * php /usr/bin/mailcheck.php
```

And in mailcheck.php, just have logic to check for entries in a database that are overdue for an email.

Or, if you just want to blindly send an email to everyone every interval, just have a sendmail() entry in mailcheck.php, and that'll do it too.